# Is it cheap to construct a const std::string from a const char* + length?

Tags: c++, string, performance, std, construct

How expensive is it to execute

```
const std::string s(my_const_char_ptr, my_length);
```

? Is there copying involved? If not, how many instructions can I expect from typical standard library implementations? Few enough to have this in performance-critical code?

... or must I get a GSL implementation and use `string_view`?

Comment: Allocating memory from the freestore is somewhat expensive in pretty much all C++ implementations. Other than that, your question is so fuzzy that the most accurate answer you could possibly expect is: It depends.

Comment: Yes there's copying. And there's simply no way of saying how many "instructions" an operation like this would use. You simply have to disassemble your code and look.

Comment: The constructor would do a heap allocation (unless `my_length` is sufficiently small and the implementation performs small string optimization), and then copy character data.

Comment: Are you looking for `string_view`?

Comment: @SergeyA: Indeed, that would work for me, I'm just hesitant about adopting all of the GSL into my project.

Comment: @einpoklum There's `string_ref` in Boost which is very much the same.

Comment: You do not have to go to GSL for this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/basic_string_view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to measure it on your target system and compilation settings if you want to know the exact answer. But for what's happening under the hood:

- If `my_length` is large enough (or the standard library's `std::string` implementation doesn't use small string optimization — which is rare), then there will be a dynamic memory allocation.
- In any case, there will be an O(n) character-by-character copy from `*my_const_char_ptr` to the `std::string`'s buffer.

Answer (score 2):

> How expensive is it to execute...

pretty cheap if you do it once

> ? Is there copying involved?

Yes, but that's the least of your worries. a linear copy is about the cheapest thing you can do in a modern architecture. (because of the pipelining, prefetching, etc etc)

> how many instructions can I expect from typical standard library implementations?

fewer than you'd think - particularly in the copy part. The implementation (built with -O2) will seek to loop-unroll, vectorise, and transfer large words at once where possible. Memory alignment will actually be the biggest arbiter of performance.

> Few enough to have this in performance-critical code?

If it's performance-critical, pre-allocate the string and re-use it (see `std::string::assign(first, last)`. Again, the copying bit is as cheap as chips. It's the memory allocation which will kill you, so do it once.

> ... or must I get a GSL implementation and use string_view?

Not unless the strings are absolutely enormous.

Comment: As long as the string is short (like under 128B), yeah copying is cheap.  The target buffer will already be hot in L1 cache if this is happening in a tight loop.  It's still obviously better to avoid the copying, because it takes instructions to do it.  If the loop is big enough that the OP can't just change the loop to using the `const char*` directly, though, then there's probably enough going on that it's not bottlenecking on instruction/uop throughput (e.g. Intel SnB-family's 4 uop per clock OOO pipeline width), so the copy latency/throughput impact is mostly hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Per the standard table 66

> `basic_string(const charT*, size_type, const Allocator&)` effects
>
> `data()`: points at the first element of an allocated copy of the array whose first element is pointed at by s
> [...]

So we are going to have an allocation and a O(N) copies where N is the size passed to the function.